# using std::freopen to redirect stderr c++

Tags: c++, io

I want to redirect all `stderr` to a file, which is also being used by my logger for the entire time the application (game) is running.

The following redirects it away from the console, but it never appears in my file, and using `fclose` after the game loop is over doesn't actually do anything, where it normally should.

```
freopen(Logger::logFile.c_str(),"a",stderr);
```

Any help would be great on how to get `stderr` to output to the text file, in a game loop.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of freopen?

Comment: Yes nothing wrong with it, it redirects away from the console, it just does print it to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might here be playing with undefined behavior...  ***because you must not use `freopen` to redirect various things to the same file.***

In the below example, depending on what file you close, you will write differently:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("                              This sentence is redirected to a file.");
//  fclose (stdout);
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stderr);
  fprintf (stderr, "This ERRORis redirected to a file.");
  //fclose (stderr);
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Here you write the *error* before the *sentence*:

```
This ERRORis redirected to a file.sentence is redirected to a file.
```

Not great. I suggest you let the OS do this *redirection to same file* work for you, e.g. in Unix / Linux:

```
./myprog.sh 2>&1
```

Comment: I am not even sure why I was asking this question for anymore so I cannot be sure if this is right or wrong. Is it better to mark as resolved or what?

Comment: @Baraphor: Do what you think is right. I should not pressure you to help me gain reputation.